# Given position, time, speed and orientation, find acceleration and velocity

Tags: math, game-physics, physics

I have the current position, time, initial speed, target speed, and orientation (heading, pitch, roll) of a flying object.

How do I calculate the current acceleration and velocity? The object already has an acceleration and velocity that needs to be taken into account.

Comment: you also need time of measurement (time since last measurement) for both cases; velocity is distance/time, while acceleration is velocity/time .. "the velocity is V meters per second", "the acceleration is A meters per second per second" (the change in velocity)

Comment: I can get that.

Comment: I think it depends on how you want to implement the physics. For example if "`thrust`" (like in airplane) is an input from the player and you want it to be directly proportional to `acceleration`, you can set the `current_velocity` as `last_velocity` + `last_acceleration` * `delta_time_frame`, and then the `acceleration` is set to be some linear function of that `thrust`. As for the target speed, I'm not sure how to implement it in this, perhaps put it into the acceleration equation?

Comment: You can approximate `acceleration = (speed[t1] - speed[t0]) / (t1 - t0)` where t0 and t1 are the last two measurements, and hopefully `t1-t0` is small enough for a good approximation. As for velocity, that's just the "length" of the speed vector: `velocity = sqrt(speed.x**2 + speed.y**2 + speed.z**2)`